# SQL code not getting picked up in Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a Database Handler java code which should execute the Select statement from the JSP. That is not happening and it is throwing the exception. I suspect, there is some JAR file issue due to which my code is not working in Websphere 8.5. The same code works in Tomcat at my Local.

Exception thrown:

```
Java.lang.NullPointerException 
     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:467) 
     at com.ids.dbmanager.DatabaseManager.executeGUCountQuery(Databa‌​seManager.java:130) 
     at com.ibm._jsp._folder._jspService(_folder.java:176) 
     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:‌​99) 
Thanks
```

Comment: Can you share some more details about the exception you're seeing?  A stack trace, at the very least, would be useful.  My guess based on the phrase "not getting picked up" is a ClassNotFoundException, but a stack trace would be helpful even if that's the case, to see what class loaders are being used.

Comment: This is the SystemErr.log from Websphere console:

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:467)
at com.ids.dbmanager.DatabaseManager.executeGUCountQuery(DatabaseManager.java:130)
at com.ibm._jsp._folder._jspService(_folder.java:176)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)

Comment: What is the JDBC driver class and how is the JDBC driver packaged?  Can you paste some of your *com.ids.dbmanager.DatabaseManager* code?  Is it packaged within your application?  I think it this is WebSphere traditional, correct?  (Or is it WebSphere Liberty?)